# compare two values in javascript works wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I try to compare some values of array and I need to get the minor value of object property but I have the next error.

this is my code:

```js
//JavaScript

var minValue = data.freight[0].localPrice;

    console.log(minValue);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.freight.length; i++) {

        console.log('----------');
        console.log(minValue);
        console.log('>');
        console.log(data.freight[i].localPrice);
        console.log('----------');

        if (minValue > data.freight[i].localPrice) {

            minValue = data.freight[i].localPrice;

            console.log('verdadero');

         }else{

            console.log('falso');

         }
      }
```

and this is the output:

[image: Why 4.27 > 160.02 it´s true?]

Why 4.27 > 160.02 it´s true?

Comment: Because those are strings not numbers.

Comment: You are comparing strings, it compares by positions and in the first position 4 > 1 that's it.

Comment: convert it to float and again try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is presumable that `localPrice` is a string. So you should use [`parseFloat()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to get the float value and get expected results when comparing.

```
var minValue = parseFloat(data.freight[0].localPrice);
```

And in your `if` statement:

```
if (minValue > parseFloat(data.freight[i].localPrice)) {

    minValue = parseFloat(data.freight[i].localPrice);

    console.log('verdadero');

}
```